# StopIteration unpredictable bug

Tags: python, python-3.x

This function gives me unpredictable `StopIteration` error. I want to understand what causes such a bug. Cause it sometimes work and sometimes doesn't:

```
def prepare_dimensions(dimensions, dim_list):
        for dimension in dimensions:
            dimension['info'] = next(dim for dim in dim_list if dimension['id'] == dim['_id'])
```

Comment: Are you able to add some sample input for the function to the question? Also show what your expected output would be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`StopIteration` will be raised by `next` if it is given an empty iterable.

If any of your `dimensions` doesn't match anything in the `dim_list` you will get this error because the list comprehension will be empty. Similarly if `dim_list` is empty you will get this error.

Comment: You are right, there was a mismatch between deimnsions and dim_list lengths.